# Delete fields from the Salesforce Data Entry Event

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, entry-criteria

I just configured a Salesforce Data Entry Event in a Journey and after running some tests I would like to delete some fields from the entry data step (those are not mandatory and were checked manually previously).

It seems the checkbox is blocked so I cannot unchecked it, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Salesforce Data Entry Events there is no way of editing the entry source configuration currently.

The only way of "modifying" it is:

1. Create a new journey version
2. Delete the Entry Event
3. Configure a new Entry Event
4. Re-configure all activities using data of that event (decision splits for example)

A Salesforce Data Entry event is only editable as long as it isn't part of any journey or journey version:

> **NOTE** Salesforce entry sources, including the Salesforce Data, Campaign, and Community entry sources, are only editable when no other journey or version uses them. You can't edit the object that a Salesforce entry source uses to decide who enters the journey. To choose a different object in a Salesforce entry source, delete and recreate the entry source.
> (Source: [Marketing Cloud Documentation - The Salesforce Data Event](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_salesforce_data_event.htm&type=5))